# How do I send data like an array from an html file to another html page?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send an array of values from an html file to another to plot a bar graph on a html page. I do not want to use any sever side languages but I am open to use js,json, jquery and ajax.

The array looks like:
        arrVisitors[0] = "a, 750";
        arrVisitors[1] = "b, 425";
        arrVisitors[2] = "c, 1000";
        arrVisitors[3] = "d, 700";
        arrVisitors[4] = "e, 800";
        arrVisitors[5] = "f, 975";
        arrVisitors[6] = "g, 375";
        arrVisitors[7] = "h, 775";
So how do I store it in the 1st html file and how do I call it in the second file where I am plotting the graph based on the values.

Comment: server side languages?

Comment: Please be a little bit more specific when asking a question

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the data as Post-Parameter to the server and use that data when processing the request for the second page.

Since you didn't specify what you want to do exactly, I can't be more precise ...

Answer (score 0):

use `$_POST['data']` to catch variable and `$.post('your.html',{data:$('form').serialize()},function(data){alert(data);})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use LocalStorage - since it's isolated per domain it will be visible across all the subpages in your domain.

- Page A: store the array you need in the localstorage.

  `localStorage.setItem("name", ['my_array'])`;
- Page B: listen for changes in the localstorage and act appriopriately when values are updated.

  `window.addEventListener("storage", my_function, false);`

No server-side language involved here. No strange hacks. Just pure HTML5.

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have pure HTML files and there is no scripting language in place...

It would be difficult to get and process data passed from one html page in another one.. 
But you can do this operation using Javascript..

Pass the data with GET method of `<form>` and try to access that data on another page with the help of javascript. You can get the entire url by

```
window.location
```

and then you can use string functions to get all possible values.

Or you can use the local storage utility of html 5.

**[Check this link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)**